# Arcanedev\LogViewer\Contracts\Utilities\Filesystem' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem with the `arcanedev/log-viewer` package on my API when it live in the server.

On my localhost, the package works fine and all my routes load the correct views, but after pushing my code on to the remote server and after i have run `composer install` when i access my web and API routes i get this error:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Class
>   'Arcanedev\LogViewer\Contracts\Utilities\Filesystem' not found

I have checked my `composer.json` file to see if the package is include, then i checked the vendor directory for  the package and i found that all the required directories files are there. I even re-required the package and ran `php artisan vendor:publish`.

I do not know where to search for a mistake or problem that may cause this problem.

here is a partial of my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel",
    "boilerplate"
],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "arcanedev/log-viewer": "~4.0",
    "arcanedev/no-captcha": "~3.0",
    "chrisbjr/api-guard": "4.*",
    "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^3.0",
    "hieu-le/active": "~3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^7.0"
```

Here is a partial of my config/app.php

```
  /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Arcanedev\LogViewer\LogViewerServiceProvider::class,
    Arcanedev\NoCaptcha\NoCaptchaServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    Creativeorange\Gravatar\GravatarServiceProvider::class,
    DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider::class,
    HieuLe\Active\ActiveServiceProvider::class,
    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
    Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,
    Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
```

And here is a list of the files in the utilities folder of the package.

> $ ls
>   Factory.php  **Filesystem.php**  LogChecker.php  LogLevels.php  LogMenu.php  LogStyler.php

I could use some assistance in solving this error, I look forward to your assistance.

Thank you i advance.

Comment: which Laravel Version are you using?

Comment: You should upload complete running project on the server including vendor dir.